# Impossible to set attachment size in test class?

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

Seeking for some insights again..

If we try to set attachmentfile.size()=200000 or anything we receive the error *Expression cannot be assigned.*

So is it really impossible to test how a method behaves when an attachment with say 25MB file size is attached to it?

Thanks!

Comment: Create attachment with some text and attach to email boady

Comment: @Sunny 25MB creating in test class is impractical and not possible .Its better not to simulate this through test class .Instead test through the UI

Comment: @MohithKumar You should have said why it's not possible. The governor limits would stop this test cold (heap size limit), automatically failing the test. It is perfectly easy to create 25MB of random data in Apex Code. You just have to know how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not write code that checks for a violation of governor limits, because you can never reach that code during normal execution. This is because a violation of any governor limit (for example, the heap size limit) will immediately result in termination of your transaction. The user will get a generic error stating that the heap size has been exceeded in that case. Write code only for exceptions and business logic you can catch or enforce, such as not allowing the user to upload an empty file, and write test methods to cover those exceptions and business logic.

**Edit:** By the way, there's a *real* neat trick for simulating read-only values, but remember that you can't save values that you do this with.

```
Attachment attachmentRecord = (Attachment)
    JSON.deserialize('{"BodyLength": 25000000}', Attachment.class);
```

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, thanks for your explanation. That was exactly my process to assert that an error message is displayed if no attachment is uploaded but users still try to submit the record..but what I was missing in the unit test is to actually upload files > 10MB size. So I ended up confirming only via UI leaving those lines of code uncovered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this will be one of those things that's impossible to test right now, like posting a message to the Connect API. You could use `Test.IsRunningTest()` to add some logic throw an exception or similar to test the uncovered code, but personally I prefer not to edit my logic just to facilitate tests.